# Get Parent + Child Wordpress Taxonomy Name/Slugs

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I got a little problem... ლ(ಠ益ಠლ)
I was looking for getting Parent + Child name (or slugs) in hierarchical form... But only for the selected ones in my post.

For example:

```
> New York (parent)
> -Rome
> -Middletown
> -Mount Vernon * (selected in post)
> -New York

> California (parent)
> -Auburn
> -Dublin
```

So I would like to receive:

```
New York
Mount Vernon
```

If possible, I'd like to choose NAME instead of SLUGS (because my cities have 2 or more names and it will have a lot of dashes -).

I was trying to use get_the_terms, but it only returns child and no parent name. In array it shows only parent id, no parent name.

My taxonomy is: property-city

And it has both cities and neiborhoods names.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Also I need to use get_the_id() instead of $Post->ID, I don't know if this is a issue because I'm not getting a good result... ᕙ(⇀‸↼‶)ᕗ

Oh! It doesn't need to come all in one string. It'd be even better if I could choose only one (city or neighborhood, instead of city AND neighborhood). ᕕ( ᐛ )ᕗ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// get the assigned taxonomy terms for "property-city"
$assigned_terms = wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'property-city', array("fields" => "all"));

// loop through the term objects
foreach($assigned_terms as $term){

    // display child term name
    echo 'Child term:'.$term->name.'<br>';

    // display parent term name
    if($term->parent != 0){
        $parent = get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent , 'property-city' );
        echo 'Parent term:'.$parent->name.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!
I just had to fix the foreach loop, assigned_terms for $assigned_terms :D

Thanks A LOT!

Comment: Woops, sorry about that!

Comment: Come on! You did pretty well :D
Thanks again!